# Android: Listview long hold context menu issue

Tags: java, android, listview, contextmenu

I'm trying to open a context menu after long holding the a listview entry and displaying various options. 
However, I'm unable as long holding is not doing/invoking anything.

**This the code that I'm using to invoke the context menu:**

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuItem delete = menu.add("delete");
    MenuItem edit = menu.add("edit");
    delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    edit.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

**I have also tried, but to no avail either:**

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, 
                View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Edit");
    menu.add(0, 2, 1, "Rename");
    menu.add(0, 3, 2, "Delete");
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    if(item.getTitle().equals("Edit")) {
        //Edit code
    } else if(item.getTitle().equals("Rename")) {
        //Rename code
    } else if(item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
        //Delete code
    }
    return true;
};
```

**MainActivity code (only relevant parts):**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private List<CountElement> myElements = new ArrayList<CountElement>();
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<CountElement> adapter;

    /*
    Users enters needed listview items, code not shown here. It works fine however - 
    all needed elements are displayed correctly.
    */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuItem delete = menu.add("delete");
        MenuItem edit = menu.add("edit");
        delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        edit.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CountElement> {
        //Custom adapter code here
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't supposed to add a context menu to a item on the adapter rather than the listview?

Comment: I do not believe so, as registerForContextMenu requires a View parameter. I may be wrong.

Comment: And the rows are views too :) I think the problem here is that the scroll event from the listview is intercepting the longpress event.

Comment: Any idea on how to combat that? (i.e. so that the scroll doesn't intercept long press). I can display the "MyListAdapter" code if needed.

Comment: Alright, I was able to figure it out. In my custom listAdapter, I added a setOnItemLongClickListener on the listView. This setOnItemLongClickListener has an alert displayed with my needed options. Thank you for the help that you provided!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I was able to figure it out. In my custom listAdapter, I added a setOnItemLongClickListener on the listView. This setOnItemLongClickListener has an alert displayed with my needed options. As so:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() { //list is my listView

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    final int pos, long id) {
            //Whatever you wanna do
            }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu. You have to create your own menu in the menu folder and after that you have to inflate it in the method onCreateContextMenu().